# React Native Flatlist Foreach Object Child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this JSON. How can I process the child object? 'item' not working 2 times.

```
[
 {
  id: 1, 
  name: 'sa'
  childs: [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: "child 1"
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    name: "child 2"
   },
  ]
 }
]

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => { return (....) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works

```
  const data = [
     {
      id: 1, 
      name: 'sa'
      childs: [
       {
        id: 1,
        name: "child 1"
       },
       {
        id: 2,
        name: "child 2"
       },
      ]
     }
    ]

<FlatList
  data={data[0].childs}
  renderItem=({item,index}) =>{<Text>item.name</Text}
/>
```